# Bibtex compilation error

Tags: bibtex, citing, auxiliary-files, compilation-error

I'm having trouble getting citations to work, apparently because of errors when I try to compile the bibliography. When I compile and build the PDF, the footnotes appear but they just appear as the tags in the underlying .bib file:

[image]

When I use the bibliography command *Tools*>>*Bibliography*, I'm returned the following error message

Process started: bibtex "MyFile".aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
The top-level auxiliary file: MyFile.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file MyFile.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file MyFile.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file MyFile.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: you are using biblatex? Then you need to use biber and not bibtex.

Comment: I was using bibtex. But I just switched the TexStudio preferences to biber and still have the same problem. Here's the output:



INFO - This is Biber 2.7
INFO - Logfile is 'MyFile.blg'
INFO - Reading 'MyFile.bcf'
INFO - Found 92 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'DKIS.bib' for section 0
INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'DKIS.bib'

Comment: WARN - BibTeX subsystem: /var/folders/s6/bxlsj_jj5bl48q6y42p5fvl80000gp/T/DHKLDKsv4A/DKIS.bib_41712.utf8, line 1820, warning: 30 characters of junk seen at toplevel
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'MitchellPrins2004' (section 0)
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'level = 4' with 'level = 2'

Comment: INFO - Sorting list 'cms/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'cms' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'MyFile.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to MyFile.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 2

Process exited normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use `\usepackage{biblatex}`
- Make `biber` default bibtex compiler in your editor
- load bibliography information in a separate file, say `ref.bib`
- add your bibliography resource in the preamble `\bibliography{ref.bib}`
- put `\printbibliography` where you want it printed
- Make sure your compilation is as follows:

`default compiler -> biber -> default compiler -> default compiler -> view pdf`

Note the double compilation. Default compiler can be pdflatex or xelatex, your choice. You should be able to edit your default compiler in your editor. Best editor in my opinion is TexStudio. You can add the series of commands there.

Comment: Thank you! I use TexStudio but am relatively new. Where should I put in the compilation instructions (default compiler -> biber -> default compiler -> default compiler -> view pdf)?

Comment: Options -> configure TexStudio. see here. https://imgur.com/JDxivee

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. Much appreciated.

Comment: then you can accept this as answer and close the question as answered